# remove new line tags when sending an email as HTML

Tags: html, email, textarea

I'm creating an email form, and I sent the following test message:

```
test







test test
```

However, I got the following email with tags and character entities included representing new lines:

```
<p>test</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>test test</p>
```

This is the php code to process the mail:

```
var $useragent      = "CodeIgniter";
var $mailpath       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"; // Sendmail path
var $protocol       = "mail";   // mail/sendmail/smtp
var $smtp_host      = "";       // SMTP Server.  Example: mail.earthlink.net
var $smtp_user      = "";       // SMTP Username
var $smtp_pass      = "";       // SMTP Password
var $smtp_port      = "25";     // SMTP Port
var $smtp_timeout   = 5;        // SMTP Timeout in seconds
var $wordwrap       = TRUE;     // TRUE/FALSE  Turns word-wrap on/off
var $wrapchars      = "76";     // Number of characters to wrap at.
var $mailtype       = "text";   // text/html  Defines email formatting
var $charset        = "utf-8";  // Default char set: iso-8859-1 or us-ascii
var $multipart      = "mixed";  // "mixed" (in the body) or "related" (separate)
var $alt_message    = '';       // Alternative message for HTML emails
var $validate       = FALSE;    // TRUE/FALSE.  Enables email validation
var $priority       = "3";      // Default priority (1 - 5)
var $newline        = "\n";     // Default newline. "\r\n" or "\n" (Use "\r\n" to comply with RFC 822)
var $crlf           = "\n";
```

Comment: $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";  Tried that?

Comment: how can I try that? where should I include that code?

Comment: In your mail header. Add your mail code so we can answer more detailed :)

Comment: perfect... I added the mail code now

Comment: the code file where your email code resides , the file which ends with .php right?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I''m using Codeigniter